Как архитектурно правильно реализовать получение данных из БД и передачу в модель?
Изучаю WPF с применением MVVM.
Модель это обычно данные, которые необходимы для UI, и некоторые методы работы с этими данными. Для доступа к данным будет создан отдельный проект. По идеи этот уровень ничего не должен знать о сущностях модели.
Есть класс Teacher и TeacherGroup (должности, которые учитель занимает, например, физик и математик).
Teacher.cs:
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public List<TeacherGroup > Groups { get; set; }
}

TeacherGroup.cs:
public class TeacherGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Это сущности модели, которые нужны View.
Как правильно получить эти данные из БД и передать в модель (заполнить сущность) именно архитектурно? Сделать какие-то классы DTO или доп. библиотеку что-то типо ObjectModel, к которой будет доступ у всех уровней?
В DAL планировал сделать метод что-то типо GetCurrentTeacher, который из базы будет получать данные о текущем учителе и группах, в которые он входит.
Если можно, то хочу получить объяснение с примерами, пожалуйста.

Ну да, чтобы разделить проекты обычно делают какие-нибудь DTO, тащат в них из БД сущности и маппером перекладывают эти DTO в модель для MVVM. Ну, примерно так.

а правильно будет, например, создать сборку в виде библиотеки классов, в которой сделать нужные интерфейсы объектов, например ITeacher и ITeacherGroup , в проекте DAL сделать реализацию этих интерфейсов и в вызывающий уровень возвращать интерфейс ITeacher ?
или в модели обязательно должны быть реализованы классы, которые необходимы для VIew? Обязательно ли модели иметь свои классы Teacher и TeacherGroup , чтобы делать из них ObservableCollection? или можно во viewmodel сделать ObservableCollection ?

Лучше почитайте какую-то литературу, статьи какие-то. Это и дело вкуса как лучше делать и зависит от размера проекта и прочих условий. Так то да, интерфейсы - это хорошо, это правильный путь к loose coupling.

я вопрос и задал потому что статей куча, и почти в каждой по разному описывается. мне бы понять для модели важно иметь свои собственные классы описывающие сущности или достаточно стороннюю библиотеку с интерфейсами этих сущностей?

Вам правильно, или абы как? Если правильно, то вы вообще не должны руководить базой, не в клиентском приложении. Для того, чтобы это сделать правильно, у вас должен быть "сервер", который имеет доступ к базе и через которого уже ваш клиент будет общаться с данными. Сервером обычно служит сайт, у которого делают, допустим, API доступ. И вот уже имея этот сервер, вы пишете клиент не под базу, а под этот сайт. Вот это будет правильной работой с базой данных. Ну а если вам нужно тяп-ляп, то берете EF, создаете CRUD класс модели, который не будет знать ничего про V и VM, да и все, вот вам MVVM.

@EvgeniyZ тоже перегибаете. Да, в больших системах такой подход является верным, но не все системы большие и не везде нужен миллион прокладок, которые еще и поддерживать вообще-то надо, так что "абы как" в некоторых случаях будет относиться и к вашему варианту из-за избыточности, если не учитывать особенности конкретной задачи/проекта/системы =)))

@rdorn Даже в мелких проектах база должна быть под защитой, а "прослойка" и является этой защитой. Или вы будете вшивать в приложение логин и пароль, в C# приложение...?) Такой подход уместен только для "сервисных утилит" (как я их называю), где идет работа с базой напрямую (создание/удаление таблиц, аккаунтов, данных, и так далее), где каждый сотрудник проверенное лицо и имеет свою учетную запись к базе с конкретными правами, но во всех других случаях, ну.. это бред.

@EvgeniyZ разумеется это не касалось приложений, работающих в агрессивной внешней среде =))) Тут я полностью согласен, но сервисные утилиты тоже пишут люди, поэтому я и не сторонник обобщать подход на все без разбора. Это мы понимаем разницу, а другие потом эти обобщения начинают транслировать куда ни попадя

@rdorn Мы ведь не обсуждаем все приложения в мире и все концепции работы с базой в мире, верно? Если человек пишет "клиент для базы" (сервисная утилита), то без проблем, ок. Или вон есть всякие SQLite и его аналоги. Мы ведь сейчас под конкретным вопросом обсуждаем конкретную реализацию. Ну а в вопросе человек пишет MVVM проект, где делит все на слои. Сам проект - это работа некое приложение для студентов/учителей (явно учебное). Ну и теперь на вопрос "Как правильно?" что, скажете "прослойка" это не ответ? Повторю "правильно". Я понимаю, что это учебный проект, но всеж...

@EvgeniyZ ок, на том и сойдемся =))) Но все же факт, что даже сервисная тулзу не стоит писать без использования того же MVVM на WPF или MVPVM на формах, хоть и можно. а иногда очень хочется =)))

@rdorn Как и не стоит использовать базу напрямую в клиентском приложение, чего порой очень сильно хочется. Это ведь не я такой плохой, а таковы, увы, реалии, ибо мы не можем ведь в клиент внедрить логин и пароль от базы, верно? А как иначе тогда решить эту задачу, без прослойки? Вот тут-то и собака зарыта... Ну а в вопросе просят "Как правильно реализовать получение данных из БД", а тут, уж извините, я не могу назвать внедрение пароля в приложение "правильным".

Data Access Layer
Уровень доступа до БД оперирует только сущностями базы данных, т.е. единица для передачи данных на этом уровне это Entity. Среди прочего, в основном тут размещён контекст и различные репозитории.
Service Layer (Business Logic Layer)
Более известный как бизнес-слой. На этом уровне, кроме сервисов, так же определяются различные Dto для передачи информации между сервисами, а так же Мапперы. Сервис, отвечающий за работу с сущностью A должен определять преобразование в AModel. Далее работа с данными осуществляется уже с Dto
Core Layer (Application Layer)
Слой, с которым взаимодействует юзер напрямую. Предыдущие слои, которых может быть на много больше, являют собой некий механизм обработки данных, который вы можете использовать, к примеру, не только для WPF, а и для других фреймворком или проектов типа WinForms или asp.net. Всё, что вам нужно это просто подключить нужные библиотеки и всё. Целевой слой уже определяет, какие данные нужно для описания той или иной страницы либо окна и определяет такой элемент как Model
UPD:
Сама структура и архитектура проекта это дело каждого, но принято хотя бы придерживаться её наличию) Основна логика, которой вы должны оперироваться строится на двух правилах

Каждый слой должен получить минимальный набор данных, с которым он сможет выполнить полагаемую на него задачу
Каждый слой не должен получить больше данных, чем предполагает сам слой приложения

Для вашего проекта, лично я бы сделал следующий план:

В DAL создаём нужные Entities, DbContext реализацию GenericRepository
В BLL создаём сервисы TeacherService и TeacherGroupService
Для каждого сервиса делаем свой набор Dto в подпапке Models
(Опционально) ставим AutoMapper и закидывай профили для маппинга в подпапдку Mappers
Инжектим DbContext в сервисы
Вытягиваем Entity
Маппим в Dto
В Application Layer инжектим нужные сервисы
Создаём папку ViewModel и своответствующие модели
Подпапка Mapping в маппинг профилями
После вызова метода сервиса маппим результат в ViewModel и возвращаем на страницу/окно

UPD2:
На счёт правил, которые нужно придерживаться. Тут имеется ввиду, что вам не нужно передавать параметры, типа PrimaryKey, CreatedAt, DeletedAt и так далее, в ViewModel, если она там не требуется. И наоборот, если вам нужно вывести дату создания или последнего обновления какой-то записи, вам ничего не мешает это сделать, поскольку эти данные входят в набор данных для описания страницы/окна
